# FileCreate without OPLOCK / Opportunistic Locking

Tags: c++, caching, networking, file-io, smb

I am looking for a way to open / create a file on a `SMB2 Windows share` without requesting an oplock (`SMB2_OPLOCK_LEVEL_LEASE`). `FileCreate()` with the flag `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` doesn't affect the behaviour.

Disabling Opportunistic Locking in the redirector is no option.

Is there a way to affect the fileopen / filecreate to not request an oplock?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. Windows atomaticaly managing opcloks on file system level.

Answer (score -1):

There is a tricky way to achieve this. Open the same file for reading from another application. If you do this before your main filecreate, it should not request oplock . If you do the same after your main filecreate, its oplock should become broken by the server.

Honestly, I am not absolutely sure about Win behavior but it wise trying imho.

Good luck

Comment: I tested in now. The open of the firest app requests and gets the oplock (seen in netmon). With the second open (same machine, different application) there isn't even one network packet created. The redirecor handles the oplocked and cached file completely. Have you seen a different behaviour?